# Can't wait with selenium-webdriver 2.45

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium-webdriver to automate browser tasks. I used to use "WebDriverWait" for wait an element before using it. Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("frame1")));
```

This doesn't work anymore with the new version 2.45 of webdriver. The argument for "until" method have been changed and I don't know how to do this now.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Documentation: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the same 2.45 version of webdriver and haven't experienced any problem yet.

Documentation: 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Sample that works perfectly to me:

```
 WebDriverWait waitSearchGrid = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            waitSearchGrid.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='clientSearchResult']/div[1]"))));
```

Comment: "ExpectedCondition" is not a valid parameter for until method. Are you sure you are using version 2.5? See this documentation and search until method: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Comment: @Nico, I am pretty sure I'm using version 2.45. You are asking about WebDriverWait and providing doc's for FluentWait - it's not the same at all. If you want to use FluentWait then use it as it described in your link:

   'Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);'

If you want to use WebDriverWait then use right search condition:
>> .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("frame1")));
>> .visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.id("frame1"))));

Comment: FluentWait is superclass of WebDriverWait, its until method comes from its father.